# <tr> height displaying incorrectly

Tags: html, html-table, tablerow

I've been beating my head against a really stupid problem for the last while. Why can't I get the cell separating the two boxes to properly display at 9px?? I've done the math a couple of times and it works out, and yet in the cell w/ the arrow pointing towards it, it's adding extra height:

[image]

I actually appears to be doubling the 9 px height set for it (18px approx). Why?? This makes no sense.

```
<!-- BIG WRAPPER TABLE FOR CENTRAL CONTENT -->
<table width="700px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="homepage">
  <tr align="center">
    <td>

      <table width="681" height="451" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3" bgcolor="#FF66CC">Image will go here</td>
          <td rowspan="3" width="9">&nbsp;</td>
          <td height="221" width="221" bgcolor="#3f7583">Text will go here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="9">
          <td height="9" width="221" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="221" width="221" bgcolor="#CC0000">Image will go here</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- END BIG WRAPPER TABLE -->
```

Comment: Are you planning on using a table for layout? You really should consider CSS instead.

Comment: It's for an e-mail campaign, so I'm sort of stuck. But when you say, "use CSS instead", do you mean divs?

Comment: Well, I don't know too much about writing for email, but I meant using CSS rules like `float`, etc. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp.

Comment: The HTML that most experts will advise you to use in e-mail newsletters is basically HTML circa 1997 because so many e-mail clients are unable to read basic CSS elements (and most don't handle divs well at all). Thanks so much for the resources on CSS though, I'll read up and keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because of your td

```
 <td height="9" width="221" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
```

It is taking the height of your `&nbsp;` when rendered with normal font size, just remove it and it should work.

Here is the [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nVXAA/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating TD's for your spacing, why not just use the CellSpacing to accomplish what you need to do:

```
<table width="700px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="homepage" style="font-size: 7pt;">
  <tr align="center">
    <td>

      <table width="681" height="451" border="0" cellspacing="9" cellpadding="0" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FF66CC">Image will go here</td>

          <td height="221" width="221" bgcolor="#3f7583">Text will go here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="221" width="221" bgcolor="#CC0000">Image will go here</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- END BIG WRAPPER TABLE -->
```

Comment: this doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/nVXAA/1/, I also thought this should but i don't know why